# If text string contains certain words, wrap those words in a span tag

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

Looking for a little help here. I have a text string like:

```
> ...And The World Laughs With You (feat Thom Yorke)
```

With `vbscript`, if the text string has `"(feat "` in it, I want to wrap the whole bracketed text in a span tag.
So, the example above would look like:

```
> ...And The World Laughs With You <span>(feat Thom Yorke)</span>
```

Hope this makes sense and thank you in advance for the help!

Cheers,
Drew

Comment: whats your question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this logic.

```
     dim str 
   str = "And The World Laughs With You (feat Thom Yorke)"

   If  INSTR(str,"(feat ") > -1 Then
        str = REPLACE(str,"(feat ","<span>(feat ") 
        str = REPLACE(str,")",")</span>") 
   End If

   Response.Write("Result:- "  + str)
```

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - I have changed code to vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

See the examples.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

Sub ReplaceCmd
    'Remove ^ from quoting command line. Quote, ampersand and brackets
    Pttn = Replace(Arg(2), "^(", "(")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^)", ")")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^&", "&")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^""", """")
    Set regEx1 = New RegExp
    If Instr(LCase(Arg(1)), "i") > 0 then
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = True
    Else
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = False
    End If 
    regEx1.Global = False
    regEx1.Pattern = Pttn 
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        Line = RegEx1.Replace(Line, Arg(3)) 
        outp.writeline Line
    Loop
End Sub
```

To use `cscript scriptname <infile >outfile`

Replace

```
filter replace {i|n} expression replace
filter repl {i|n} expression replace
```

Finds and replaces text using regular expressions.

Also used to extract substrings from a file.

Ampersands and brackets in expression must be escaped with the caret. Do not escape carets. Use hexidecimal code \x22 for quotes.

SearchOptions

i - ignore case
n - none
Expression

Regular Expression Reference

Replace

The text to replace. Use $1, $2, $..., $n to specify sub matches in the replace string

Example

```
filter replace i "=" "No equal sign" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This searches for text within square brackets and replaces the line with cat followed by the text within brackets

```
Filter replace i "^\[^(.*^)\]" "cat$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches for any text and prints from the 11th character to the end of the line.

```
Filter replace i "^.{10}^(.*^)$" "$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches a CSV file and prints the second and fourth field

```
Filter replace i "^.+,^(.+^),.+,^(.+^)$" "$1,$2" < csv.txt
```