# Batch looping through directory find all XML and replace a certain (unknown) value with another (known) value

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, findstr

Just a question, I don't know if this is possible but let me explain it by example.

XML (containing several values)

```
<WORKFLOW DESCRIPTION ="" ISENABLED ="YES" ISRUNNABLESERVICE ="NO" ISSERVICE ="NO" ISVALID ="YES" NAME ="DIMENSIONS" REUSABLE_SCHEDULER ="NO" SCHEDULERNAME ="Scheduler" SERVERNAME ="SERVER_NAME_DUMMY" SERVER_DOMAINNAME ="Domain_DUMMY" SUSPEND_ON_ERROR ="NO" TASKS_MUST_RUN_ON_SERVER ="NO" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
```

I want to be able to catch with findstr (unless there is a better way) SERVERNAME = (this occurs only once in the whole document) and replace the value of it by SERVER_NAME_PROPER to get the following result:

SERVERNAME ="SERVER_NAME_PROPER".

The problem is I don't know the value of SERVERNAME so i cant strictly search on SERVER_NAME_DUMMY (i don't know the length either, i saw string manipulation by character sets). Also the lines just continues with other values and elements after it (no end line manipulation). Maybe it is wise to search for SERVERNAME =(promt value) and stop before SERVERDOMAIN_NAME. Because the value is after SERVERNAME= **"VALUE"** and before SERVERDOMAIN_NAME.

I know that after SERVERNAME = the value needs to be replaced by my hardcoded value. If i can preform this then i can make in batch a FOR command to loop all files in the whole directory and preform this certain command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a Replace script here 2 days ago [If text string contains certain words, wrap those words in a span tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29483379/if-text-string-contains-certain-words-wrap-those-words-in-a-span-tag/29483440#29483440).

Findstr

```
"^(SERVERNAME=\x22^)^([a-z]+^)^(\x22^)"
```

Replace with

```
$1WHATEVERYOUWANT$3
```

$1 is first set brackets, $2 second, and $3 third. Above carets are escaping it for CMD - it looks like this after parsing `(SERVERNAME=")([a-z]+)(")`

Comment: Serenity thank you for your post but i can't seem to get it working?

Comment: $1 contains `Servername="`, $2 contains the actual servername alpha only, if using underscore for real, change `[a-z]` to `[a-z_]`. I am only specifing lower case as I expect you would run it with ignore case option. Also as that code is lifted from a file of similar functions you need to remove the lines `Sub ReplaceCmd` and `End Sub`. Then `cscript //nologo "C:\path to script\script.vbs" "" i "^(SERVERNAME=\x22^)^([a-z_]+^)^(\x22^)" < "c:\filetoprocess.txt" > Outputfile.txt`.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121 is where you can download **filter0.8.zip** as a file easy to use. Then `Filter replace i "^(SERVERNAME=\x22^)^([a-z_]+^)^(\x22^)" "$1YourServerName$3" < csv.txt > output.txt`. Filter has 19 text file functions and many options and is sample code for vbs processing of text files. Showing how easy it is.

Comment: Serenity,I don't know what is going on. You want me to create a vbs script? I am not getting howto parse this and replace the value with a hardcoded value.

Can you please paste the script to change the value after findstr?

I am sorry to not understand this:(

Comment: You can't use findstr. It doesn't do replace. If you want a replace program you have to make your own.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you work with HTML or XML, it's always best to parse it *as* HTML or XML, rather than trying to scrape and hack it as text.  That way, as long as it's valid markup, you are not so dependent upon formatting.

For working with XML, you can use the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object with Windows Script Host fairly intuitively (or at least hopefully you can follow the logic in my demonstration below).  Here's a hybrid batch + JScript solution.  Save it with a .bat extension and salt to taste.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "attribute=SERVERNAME"
set "new_value=This works."

for %%I in (*.xml) do (
    rem // invoke JScript for each XML file
    cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%%~I" "%attribute%" "%new_value%"
)

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { file: WSH.Arguments(0), attr: WSH.Arguments(1), val: WSH.Arguments(2) };

DOM.load(args.file);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
   WSH.Echo(DOM.parseError.reason);
   WSH.Quit(1);
}

for (var d = DOM.selectNodes('//*[@' + args.attr + ']'), i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
    d[i].setAttribute(args.attr, args.val);

DOM.save(args.file);
```